# How change font with latex text in R plot?

Tags: r, latex

I need to write a text, in bold face, in an R plot, using latex content but also containing a value coming from a variable.

Is there a way to write in bf a latex text containing also a value from a variable?

```
t1 <- TeX(paste("$\\textbf{\\left[\\frac{M}{L}\\right]_d =}$", sprintf(fmt="%.3f",XML), sep=""))

text(PosX1,PosY, t1, adj=c(0,0), cex=1.0, font=2)
```

In that case, the variable is XML, but putting `font=2` does not change the font of the value of XML...

Here I wrote an example with a fake plot. The M/L written with TeX is in bf and I would like to have the value 0.001 value from the variable also in bf.

```
library(graphics)
library(latex2exp)

pdf(file="Test2.pdf", 15, 10)
par(mar=c(5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.0))
XML = 0.001
x = seq(0,40, 0.2)
y = 1*exp(-((x - 20)/5)^2)
plot(x,y, pch=19, cex=1.0, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
#
PosX = 5
PosY = 0.8
t1 <- TeX(paste("$\\textbf{\\left[\\frac{M}{L}\\right] =}$",    sprintf(fmt="%.3f",XML), sep=""))
text(PosX,PosY, t1, adj=c(0,0), cex=1.0, font=2)

dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] and explain the expected output? Things that are unclear: Sample value for `XML`, where does `TeX()` come from, ...

Comment: I just add a small example describing what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two changes:

- use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf¸ since you are in math mode
- extend the range of `\mathbf` and math mode to include the number

Combined:

```
library(graphics)
library(latex2exp)

pdf(file="Test2.pdf", 15, 10)
par(mar=c(5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.0))
XML = 0.001
x = seq(0,40, 0.2)
y = 1*exp(-((x - 20)/5)^2)
plot(x,y, pch=19, cex=1.0, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
#
PosX = 5
PosY = 0.8
t1 <- TeX(paste("$\\mathbf{\\left[\\frac{M}{L}\\right] =",
                 sprintf(fmt="%.3f",XML),
                 "}$",
                 sep=""))
text(PosX,PosY, t1, adj=c(0,0), cex=1.0, font=2)

dev.off()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, it is working just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @HenriPlana You are welcome. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I have clicked on the arrow "This answer is useful", I hope it is ok.

Comment: @HenriPlana THat's ok. If you want to mark the answer as "accepted" you can also click the check mark, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers