# Using Latex math fonts in R plots

Tags: r, latex, latex2exp

I am frequently using Latex to use custom math expressions in titles and axis labels of R plots.
As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots), this can be achieved using the `latex2exp` package. Is it somehow possible to include Latex special fonts for mathmode?
Specifically, I am looking for a way to include `\mathcal` and `\mathbb` symbols in R plots.
Of these, `\mathbb` might be harder, because it requires a Latex package (usually amsfonts). According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode), `\mathcal` does not require any Latex packages, but it still does not seem to work.

Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

# this works:
ggplot() + ggtitle(TeX('$\\alpha + \\sum_{n = 1}^\\infty \\frac{1}{n^2}$'))
```

[image]

```r
# this does not:
ggplot() + ggtitle(TeX('$\\mathcal{A} + \\mathbf{C}$'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The same issue occurs in base R plotting, so it's not a `ggplot` issue.

According to [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892683/how-change-font-with-latex-text-in-r-plot), at least `\mathbf` should work as used above, but it doesn't for me. When I copy-paste the example from the reply and run it, the graphics device writes out "mathbf", as in my example above.

Comment: Package latex2exp only translates a latex formula to a plotmath expression. Your actual question is if these fonts can be used in a plotmath expression. I'm 90 % sure that the answer to that is "no".

Comment: `latex2exp_supported()` does not return `mathcal`.

Comment: You can use **tikzDevice** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer part of this,  I'm quoting from `?text` and `?par`  , describing some of the possible arguments. As you can see, access to arbitrary fonts from your machine's OS is not generally possible when creating the graphs inside `R`.  However, per Stephane Laurent's comment, I think the `tikzDevice` package allows you to define a graph which will not actually come into existence, so to speak, until the output from `R` is rendered with a TeX application. This allows you to specify any font inside LaTeX commands.

> family
> The name of a font family for drawing text. The maximum allowed
> length is 200 bytes. This name gets mapped by each graphics device to
> a device-specific font description. The default value is "" which
> means that the default device fonts will be used (and what those are
> should be listed on the help page for the device). Standard values are
> "serif", "sans" and "mono", and the Hershey font families are also
> available. (Devices may define others, and some devices will ignore
> this setting completely. Names starting with "Hershey" are treated
> specially and should only be used for the built-in Hershey font
> families.) This can be specified inline for text.
>
> font
> An integer which specifies which font to use for text. If
> possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to plain text
> (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4 to bold italic. Also,
> font 5 is expected to be the symbol font, in Adobe symbol encoding. On
> some devices font families can be selected by family to choose
> different sets of 5 fonts.